# Restructure a panel dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, panel

I have a data frame with the following panel structure. However, I want to change the structure, so the columns will be collapse and corresponds to the value measured in a given year.

```
    y <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
                year = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2012, 2013, 2014),
                P2012 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
                P2013 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                P2014 = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1))

  id year P2012 P2013 P2014
1  1 2012     1     2     3
2  1 2013     1     2     3
3  1 2014     1     2     3
4  2 2012     2     1     2
5  2 2013     2     1     2
6  2 2014     2     1     2
7  3 2012     3     1     1
8  3 2013     3     1     1
9  3 2014     3     1     1
```

What I want is that i only get one column, consisting of the values from the other three columns.

```
  id year P2012 P2013 P2014 P
1  1 2012     1     2     3 1
2  1 2013     1     2     3 2
3  1 2014     1     2     3 3
4  2 2012     2     1     2 2
5  2 2013     2     1     2 1
6  2 2014     2     1     2 2
7  3 2012     3     1     1 3
8  3 2013     3     1     1 1
9  3 2014     3     1     1 1
```

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
y %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(P =  get(str_subset(names(y)[3:5], as.character(year)))) %>% 
    ungroup
# A tibble: 9 x 6
     id  year P2012 P2013 P2014     P
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  2012     1     2     3     1
2     1  2013     1     2     3     2
3     1  2014     1     2     3     3
4     2  2012     2     1     2     2
5     2  2013     2     1     2     1
6     2  2014     2     1     2     2
7     3  2012     3     1     1     3
8     3  2013     3     1     1     1
9     3  2014     3     1     1     1
```

Comment: So the problem is now, that I have more than just three columns, that I need to do the same with, which is not systematically placed in the data frame. Lets say, all of the contains "004" in the end of the column name. Any idea how to accomplish the same?

Comment: I'm very sorry. How do I accept answers? I thought i just upvote it? I haven't really figure out how to do this in here? Really don't want to offend anyone and I'm glad for the great answers I'm getting in here.

Comment: I totally get in. I just haven't been aware of rules in here. I have accepted the answers, you were giving me, as it was helpfull and did what it should.

Comment: @R9413 Regarding your new question are you saying that column names are `P004`, 'Q004` etc.  and what will be the 'year' part then

Comment: Yes, exactly - so instead of P2021 Pxxx - all that the column names have in common, is the "004" in the end of the names. However, I want the code to give med the P column, as the code that you provide me with gives.

Comment: @R9413 To be exact, can you update your post with a new example so that it is more clear to me with the expected output.

Comment: @R9413 it is just to avoid any confusion because if I give an incorrect one, you will come back again :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use matrix subsetting to extract the corresponding value for each year.

```
y$P <- y[cbind(1:nrow(y), match(paste0('P', y$year), names(y)))]

y
#  id year P2012 P2013 P2014 P
#1  1 2012     1     2     3 1
#2  1 2013     1     2     3 2
#3  1 2014     1     2     3 3
#4  2 2012     2     1     2 2
#5  2 2013     2     1     2 1
#6  2 2014     2     1     2 2
#7  3 2012     3     1     1 3
#8  3 2013     3     1     1 1
#9  3 2014     3     1     1 1
```

Comment: So the problem is now, that I have more than just three columns, that I need to do the same with, which is not systematically placed in the data frame. Lets say, all of the contains "004" in the end of the column name. Any idea how to accomplish the same?

Comment: I think it would be better if you ask that as a new question.